# How to close the child form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using MDI and Child Forms

Code.

```
childform_load

Me.MdiParent = MDIMain
```

'

```
 Private Sub form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
     If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
         Me.Close()
     End If
 End Sub
```

The above code is working for MDI Form (form name is mdiform1), but not working for child form1, when I press the escape key, it is closing the MDI Form instead of Child form.

I check the Child Form Name also, name is form1 only.

What was the problem, i need to change any property of child form.

Need code help

Comment: Do you have the child forms capturing Keydown as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then
            For Each child As Form In Me.MdiParent.MdiChildren
                child.Close()
            Next child
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your trying to fire the Child form event its firing the parent form "form1_KeyDown" event.

Answer (score 0):

**It seems to be because of the (Key preview) property of the forms.**
So try to set Key preview False in MDIMain form, And set it true in the child form.